Could someone explain "The subsets of Polynomials to degree n is not a subspace of Polynomials on [0,1]"
The explanation my notes gives is that "This is because the sum of two polynomials of equal degree can have a lesser degree".
I am not seeing how this is valid, if you add for example $$ 
P_1= 2x^3 -5x \\
P_2=-2x^3 +5x^2 \\
P_1+P_2 = 0x^3 + 5x^2 - 5x$$
would you not results in a $P_3$ polynomial still, since you can think of $0x^3$ as a vector of $P_3$ still.

The degree of a polynomial is defined as the largest of the exponents among all nonzero terms. In your example, $P_1 + P_2$ is a polynomial of degree $2$, so it does not belong to the subset of polynomials of degree $3$.

Thank you, that clears it up. I overlooked that part of the definition.

It seems to me that a simpler argument that the degree-$n$ polynomials are not a vector space is: they do not contain a zero vector.

In your example you have the sum of $P_1+P_2$ defined with a $0x^3$ term. If we accept this, then any polynomial can be defined to any higher power. For example, the quadratic (degree 2) $$x^2+x+1 = 0x^4+x^2+x+1$$ Would this be degree 4?

Nope. Zero terms do not define the polynomial, only highest degree of non-zero term.
